# access S3 using aws sdk without TLS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Recently i started integrating S3 object store using aws sdk (Java) and was able to understand aws sdk to create a AmazonS3 client for document uploads and downloads.
All this is fine until i started testing where i am facing the below cert related issue as it appears. Now i am wondering if I could use http instead of https to make the sdk not to worry about TLS since it is plain http.
Is there a way to force asw sdk to use http only but not https so it doesn't follow this code stack and error out.
I am using this maven dependency

```
 <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
 <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bundle</artifactId>
 <version>1.12.261</version>
```

```html
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLSContext\\n\\tat java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)\\n\\tat java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)\\n\\tat java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1918)\\n\\tat java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1894)\\n\\tat java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)\\n\\tat java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)\\n\\tat java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:168)\\n\\tat com.amazonaws.internal.SdkSSLContext.getPreferredSSLContext(SdkSSLContext.java:36)\\n\\tat com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.getPreferredSocketFactory(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:92)\\n\\tat com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:66)\\n\\tat com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:59)\\n\\tat com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:50)\\n\\tat com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:38)\\n\\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:347)\\n\\tat com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:331)\\n\\tat com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:239)\\n\\tat com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:225)\\n\\tat com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:723)\\n\\tat com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Builder$1.apply(AmazonS3Builder.java:35)\\n\\tat com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Builder$1.apply(AmazonS3Builder.java:32)\\n\\tat com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder.build(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.java:64)\\n\\tat com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder.build(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.java:28)\\n\\tat com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)\\n\\tat
```

Comment: FYI, If this is work-related using HTTP for document transfers may not pass security standards like PCI, SOC2, TxRAMP, and might cause GDPR issues for not securing personal information if the documents contain any.

Comment: WHy are you using a Java V1 that is NOT best practice. You should be looking at using AWS SDK for Java V2. See the AWS DEV Guide here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html

Comment: @smac2020 - surely will try with V2, wondering what could be the cause of issue, i am not able to figure out why the aws client sdk throws that TLSContext not found error